# Can I ask whether specific compilers/engines perform certain optimizations?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I want to know whether the three most prevalent JavaScript engines (those in Chrome, FF,and IE) are known to perform certain optimizations. For instance, I might ask whether simple functions are inlined or optimized in any other way:

```
var add = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

Is this an acceptable place to ask?

Answer (score 2):

No. This site is about *conceptual* questions regarding software development – see the [help center](/help/on-topic) for details.. You can ask about compiler concepts or language concepts or design concepts, but asking about specific, concrete implementation details of some language implementation is not generally on-topic here.

A question about using a JavaScript API would be on-topic for Stack Overflow, as would be a question about using a specific JS implementation. However, what you're inquiring about is probably an undocumented implementation detail that's subject to unannounced change – all that matters is that the JS engine conforms to the spec and is as fast as possible. Therefore, this could be seen as a “how should we know, ask these engine's developers directly”-kind of question that would run into a risk of being closed on SO as well.

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/839601) :)